# How can I find when a user was added to an Azure AD Group, using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I find when a user was added to an Azure AD Group, using the Microsoft Graph API

```
GET /groups/{id}/members
```

Are any query parameters required in order to obtain the added date?

Comment: @Sridevi createdDateTime is related to the date and time the user (entity that is a member of the group) was created.

Comment: "createdDateTime" = Time when email was created in the mailbox's folder.
I want when a user was added to an Azure AD Group

Comment: @Sridevi Is it possible through Graph API?

Comment: Try this query: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName+eq+'Add+member+to+group'+and+targetResources/any(c:c/id+eq+'UserID') and result eq 'success'&$orderby=activityDateTime desc`

Answer (score 0):

To find **when** a user was added to an Azure AD Group via MS Graph API, you can make use of below query:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName+eq+'Add+member+to+group'+and+targetResources/any(c:c/id+eq+'UserID') and result eq 'success'&$orderby=activityDateTime desc
```

I have one **Azure AD group** with members like below:

[image]

When I ran below query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I got **response** with `activityDateTime` parameter like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits?$filter=activityDisplayName+eq+'Add+member+to+group'+and+targetResources/any(c:c/id+eq+'UserID') and result eq 'success'&$orderby=activityDateTime desc
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to verify group details in `modifiedProperties` of targetResources from **response** like this:

[image]